# ORA-02291: integrity constraint (H00300581.FK_CLASSES) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys

When I do the insert it give me this error:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (H00300581.FK_CLASSES) violated - parent key not found

and this error is happening for all the inserts into registration table. I need help on this, please try fixing it for me.

Is it from the foreign key that is in the tables? What it could be because I tried everything, and it didn't work.

CREATING TABLES

```
drop table g3_trainers CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
drop table g3_classes CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
drop table g3_members CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
drop table g3_registration CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE G3_TRAINERS
(
TRAINER_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
TRAINER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DOB DATE NOT NULL,
SPECIALITY VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (TRAINER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE G3_CLASSES
(
CLASS_NUM VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
TRAINER_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
CLASS_TITLE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
END_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
COST NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (CLASS_NUM),
CONSTRAINT fk_TRAINERS FOREIGN KEY(TRAINER_ID) REFERENCES G3_TRAINERS(TRAINER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE G3_MEMBERS
(
MEMBER_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
MEMBER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
MEMBER_AGE NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
GENDER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CHECK (regexp_like (PHONE_NUMBER,'^(\d{3}-\d{3}-?\d{4}|\d{10})$')),
CHECK (MEMBER_AGE>=17),
CHECK(MEMBER_AGE NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'),
PRIMARY KEY  (MEMBER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE G3_REGISTRATION
(
REGISTRATION_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
MEMBER_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT_TO_PAY NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
CLASS_NUM VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (REGISTRATION_ID),
CONSTRAINT fk_MEMBERS FOREIGN KEY(MEMBER_ID) REFERENCES G3_MEMBERS(MEMBER_ID),
CONSTRAINT fk_CLASSES FOREIGN KEY(CLASS_NUM) REFERENCES G3_CLASSES(CLASS_NUM)
);
```

CREATING SEQUENCE

```
CREATE SEQUENCE G3_TRAINER_Seq
 START WITH     10001
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE G3_MEMBER_Seq
 START WITH     20001
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE G3_CLASSE_Seq
 START WITH     30001
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

CREATE SEQUENCE G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq
 START WITH     40001
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

Trainer Data

```
 INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB, SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)
 VALUES (G3_TRAINER_Seq.nextVal, 'Ahmed', 'Eygpt', '2/3/1988', 'Body Building', 'I describe my self as an active guy i workout everyday and thats why i desided to train people to be good as me');

 INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB, SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)
 VALUES (G3_TRAINER_Seq.nextVal, 'John', 'Canada', '4/6/1987', 'Crossfit', 'I like being healthy and work as much as i can to be fit and to have a great life');

 INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB, SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)
 VALUES (G3_TRAINER_Seq.nextVal, 'Sara', 'Canada', '9/1/1990', 'Yoga', 'I like interacting with poeple, and to teach them how yoga will be a very good source of flexing and relaxing your body');

 INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB, SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)
 VALUES (G3_TRAINER_Seq.nextVal, 'Jun', 'China', '12/4/1981', 'Crossfit', 'I describe my self as an daily working guy i like my job because i get to know more about people and i teach many people how to be fit');

  INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB, SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)
 VALUES (G3_TRAINER_Seq.nextVal, 'Mike', 'Ohio', '2/22/1981', 'Body Building', 'Being strong and big is what i am aiming for, i like keeping my diet healthy and to train poeple to be healthy and big like me');

 INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB, SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)
 VALUES (G3_TRAINER_Seq.nextVal, 'Mia', 'Germany', '12/12/1987', 'Yoga', 'I describe myself as a hard working i love my job and i love my members');

 INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB, SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)
 VALUES (G3_TRAINER_Seq.nextVal, 'Essam', 'UAE', '1/5/1980', 'Body Building', 'I am a hard worker and i like to train my members and i want them to be healthy and strong');
```

Class Data

```
 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10001, 'Weight Lifting Class', '1/12/2017', '1/1/2018', 1150);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10001, 'Weight Lifting Class', '1/2/2018', '1/3/2018', 1150);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10002, 'Body Weight Class', '2/1/2018', '2/2/2018', 950);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10003, 'Yoga Class', '3/2/2018', '3/3/2018', 750);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10003, 'Yoga Class', '5/5/2018', '5/6/2018', 750);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10004, 'Body Weight Class', '10/2/2018', '10/3/2018', 950);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10004, 'Body Weight Class', '10/4/2018', '10/5/2018', 950);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10005, 'Weight Lifting Class', '12/20/2017', '1/20/2018', 1150);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10005, 'Weight Lifting Class', '2/20/2018', '3/20/2018', 1150);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10005, 'Weight Lifting Class', '4/20/2018', '5/20/2018', 1150);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10006, 'Yoga Class', '12/28/2017', '1/28/2018', 750);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10007, 'Weight Lifting Class', '10/3/2018', '10/4/2018', 1150);

 INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
 VALUES (G3_CLASSE_Seq.nextVal, 10007, 'Weight Lifting Class', '10/5/2018', '10/6/2018', 1150);
```

MEMBER DATA

```
 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Mohammed', '21', 'Male', '0502202212');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Afra', '28', 'Female', '0555544558');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Essa', '30', 'Male', '0555544558');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Ahmed', '19', 'Male', '0563020300');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Alex', '25', 'Female', '0521022932');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Abdulla', '24', 'Male', '0504493393');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Abdulrahman', '20', 'Male', '0502292290');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Olivia', '21', 'Female', '0561020200');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Omar', '30', 'Male', '0502503323');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Nasser', '29', 'Male', '0504334439');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Sophia', '22', 'Female', '0561616316');

 INSERT INTO G3_MEMBERS (MEMBER_ID, MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_AGE, GENDER, PHONE_NUMBER)
 VALUES (G3_MEMBER_Seq.nextVal, 'Nadia', '21', 'Female', '0507797786');
```

Registration Data

```
 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20001, 1150, 30001);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20001, 750, 30004);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20002, 750, 30004);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20002, 950, 30006);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20003, 1150, 30001);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20003, 1150, 300010);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20004, 950, 30006);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20004, 1150, 30010);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20005, 1150, 30007);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20005, 750, 30011);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20006, 1150, 30013);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20006, 1150, 30012);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20007, 1150, 30009);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20007, 750, 30011);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20008, 1150, 30008);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20008, 750, 30011);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20009, 1150, 30013);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20009, 750, 30005);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20010, 1150, 30013);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20010, 1150, 30012);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20010, 950, 30007);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20011, 1150, 30013);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20011, 750, 30005);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20012, 750, 30004);

 INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID, AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)
 VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal, 20012, 1150, 30009);
```

Comment: Your script has too many errors. There are missing commas in several places. There are typos in the sequence names which you are using in your insert statements . Fix these things first.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak i fix the small problems how can i add the code?

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak i have edited it take a look at it

Comment: @abdulrahmanarab by the way, remove spaces in between `column names` in `create sentences`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan sorry i didnt know where exactly to remove spaces

Comment: @abdulrahmanarab i've just edited.

Answer (score 0):

`commas` are missing for the most of statements, such as :

> between `'Eygpt'` & `'12/3/1988'` in :
>
> ```
>  INSERT INTO G3_TRAINERS (TRAINER_ID, TRAINER_NAME, COUNTRY, DOB,
>  SPECIALITY, DESCRIPTION)  VALUES (G3_TRAINERS_Seq.nextVal, 'Ahmed',
>  'Eygpt' '12/3/1988', 'Body Building', 'I describe my self as an active
>  guy i workout everyday and thats why i desided to train people to be
>  good as me');
> ```

OR

> between `'Weight Lifting Class'` & `'1/12/2017'`
>
> ```
>  INSERT INTO G3_CLASSES (CLASS_NUM, TRAINER_ID, CLASS_TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, COST)
>  VALUES (G3_CLASSES_Seq.nextVal, 10001, 'Weight Lifting Class' '1/12/2017', '1/1/2018', 1150);
> ```

You have `CONSTRAINT fk_CLASSES FOREIGN KEY(CLASS_NUM) REFERENCES G3_CLASSES(CLASS_NUM)` as constraint

you have `G3_CLASSES_Seq` sequence to populate the class_num column of `g3_classes` table that should be convenient with `fk_CLASSES FOREIGN KEY`, but you have another sequence `G3_CLASSE_Seq` starting with `30000`. By the way, it seems it should be started with `30001`

> i.e. Pay attention that `G3_CLASSE_Seq` and `G3_CLASSES_Seq` are different.

by the way, remove spaces in between `column names` in `create sentences` like following :

as an example, convert this

```
CREATE TABLE G3_TRAINERS
(

TRAINER_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
TRAINER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DOB DATE NOT NULL,
SPECIALITY VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY  (TRAINER_ID)

);
```

to this :

```
CREATE TABLE G3_TRAINERS
(
TRAINER_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
TRAINER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DOB DATE NOT NULL,
SPECIALITY VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (TRAINER_ID)
);
```

And there's another problem in the following statement ( `300010` )

> INSERT INTO G3_REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_ID, MEMBER_ID,
>   AMOUNT_TO_PAY, CLASS_NUM)  VALUES (G3_REGISTRATIONS_Seq.nextVal,
>   20003, 1150, `300010`);

Comment: thank you so much, that solved one of my other problem but i posted the main problem

Comment: @abdulrahmanarab please look at my last edit related to foreign key and sequences.

Comment: @abdulrahmanarab i think, problem is related not to use `G3_CLASSE_Seq`(you should use this, starting with 30001). You're using `G3_CLASSES_Seq` instead.

Comment: ohh ok so it start incremented from 30001 not 30000